# How to custom style a bootstrap 3 component provided by a gem in rails 4 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, rubygems, bootstrap-datetimepicker

What is the rails way to **custom style a component** (in this case [bootstrap 3 datetime picker](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails)) **provided in a gem**?

Using Rails 4 asset pipeline

I could edit the original css in the gem, but I would rather override it!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called custom.scss.css in your assets/css folder and just overwrite the bootstrap styles, for example:

```
.btn{
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: yeah sure but then I would need to know what is in the other css file, so it would possibly be easier to pull out that css file in the vendor folder an disregard the file in the gem altogether.